# Create discrete Hidden Markov Model with matrix (NxN) observations?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

In all of the discrete HMMs that I have seen, the observation data has consisted of a stream of integers. However what happens if the observations are actually discrete feature vectors? For example, what if I am trying to use HMMs to learn gesture recognition on greyscale intensity values of video frames? That is, each observation is described by an nxn matrix, rather than a single value? How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a discrete [Multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) for the emission component of the HMM. For example each state emits an array of integer of length `n*n` with values between 0 to 255 denoting the pixel intensities (grayscale).

Of course if the values are continuous (floating point numbers), just use the Multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the library you want to use, `ObservationVectors` might serve well. You can flatten the matrix to a n²-dimensional vector and train a model with verified data. Then you are able to detect any gesture from a sequence of vector observations.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you know of any libraries that support observation vectors?